# login and validation error in django

Tags: django-models

I'm a newbie to python and django framework.Please anyone help me where I'm going Wrong,I'm doing simple registration form and login ,here registration form works and stores the  form data in the database but i'm not able to login and do verification for my username and password.Thanks in advance

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from core import views as core_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', core_views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^signup/$', core_views.signup, name='signup'),
url(r'^login/$', 
 auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), 
name='login'),
 url(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Core

 class Registrationform(forms.ModelForm):
       username = forms.CharField(max_length=15,label="Username")
      firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=15,label="Firstname")
      lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=15,label="Lastname")
      email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
      password = forms.CharField 
      (widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=True,label="Password")
     password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, 
     required=True,label="PasswordConfirmation")

    class Meta:
         model=Core
         fields= 
   ("username","firstname","lastname","email","password","password1",)
```

views.py

```
   from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
   from .form import Registrationform
   from django.contrib import messages
   from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
   def home(request):
       return render(request,'home.html')

  def signup(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Registrationform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           user=form.save()
           username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
           firstname = form.cleaned_data.get('firstname')
           lastname = form.cleaned_data.get('lastname')
           email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
           password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
           user=authenticate(username=username,firstname=firstname,
           lastname=lastname,email=email,password=password)
           login(request,user)
           return render(request,'home')
     else:
          form = Registrationform()

    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
  def login(request):
      if request == 'POST' :
         username = request.POST['username']
         password = request.POST['password1']
         user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
         if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return render(request,'home.html')
         else:
            return render(request,"invalid.html")
     else:
        return render(request,'invalid.html')
```

login.html

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
        {{ form.as_p }}
          <div style="text-align: center;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted text-center">
      New to myapp?<a href="{% url 'signup' %}"> Sign up</a>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with in bulit app `auth`. we don't need to explicitly write models for User. change your code like below.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Reference: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/views/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/models/

Comment: Thanks! but my problem is not solved, i did  what u told and getting error -'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'